Google calendar API country code not working anymore
I am trying to add public holidays to my calendar in my application. I have a Google Cloud account and created a project from which I can fetch public holidays data.
I have a short Python script that can fetch the data from the API. In this gist(https://gist.github.com/seanblanchfield/4df78d73c85b149133615c7953894076), most of the country codes are listed, and all of them worked until 20.05.2024. However, the Swiss (ch.ch) and Canadian (ca.canadian) codes, for example, return an empty items list. The request is still made, but no public holidays are received. The South African (za.sa) code, on the other hand, still returns public holidays.
Does anyone have the same problem, or am I doing something wrong?
Python script that I am currently using:
import requests

BASE_CALENDAR_URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars"
BASE_CALENDAR_ID_FOR_PUBLIC_HOLIDAY = "holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com"
API_KEY = "your api key here from the google cloud console (https://console.cloud.google.com)"
CALENDAR_REGIONS = ["ch.ch", "ca.canadian", "za.sa"] # delete the regions you don't want to see

# Iterate through each region

for region in CALENDAR_REGIONS:
# Making a fetch request for the current region
url = f"{BASE_CALENDAR_URL}/{region}%23{BASE_CALENDAR_ID_FOR_PUBLIC_HOLIDAY}/events?key={API_KEY}"

    response = requests.get(url)
    
    # Check if the request was successful
    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.json()
        holidays = data
        print(holidays)
    else:
        print(f"Error fetching data for {region}. Status code: {response.status_code}")
        print("Response content:", response.content)


I would greatly appreciate any ideas or hints as to why the Google Calendar API stopped working.
